# Android Jetpack Compose, How to get Semantics from Another Composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

## Introduction

I made a wrapper which gives a `Composable` a disabled look and prevents click events from being passed to it.

```
@Composable
fun DisableOverlay(enabled: Boolean, alpha: Float = 0.45F, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    if (enabled) {
        content()
    } else {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .alpha(alpha)
        ) {
            content()

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .clickable(enabled = false){
                    //absorb the clicks
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Below is an example usage.

```
        DisableOverlay(enabled = false) {
            Column{
                Text(text = "Some Text")
            }
        }
```

## The Problem

It works fine but has some issues with accessibility reader (TalkBack) is on. The reader does not read the `content` Composable on some devices. It reads the text on Pixel devices but not Samsung. I noticed on the Pixel device it read the text content but does not honour any semantics set on it i.e. a `contentDescription`.

For example, the reader would not read "my content description" on this `Text`.

```
        DisableOverlay(enabled = false) {
            Column{
                Text(text = "Some Text", 
                    modifier = Modifier.semantics { 
                        contentDescription = "my content description"
                })
            }
        }
```

## Attempted Solution 1 (FAILED)

I added `clearAndSetSemantics` on the `Box` that overlaps the content composable. My theory was the reader can ignore the element and just read out `content`. This did not work, the reader completely skips the content.

```
fun DisableOverlay(enabled: Boolean, alpha: Float = 0.45F, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    if (enabled) {
        content()
    } else {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .alpha(alpha)
        ) {
            content()

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .clearAndSetSemantics {

                }
                .clickable(enabled = false){
                    //absorb the clicks
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

## Attempted Solution 2 (FAILED)

I found a property called `invisibleToUser()`. This had the same effect as `clearAndSetSemantics` seen in Solution 1.

```
.semantics {
    invisibleToUser()
}
```

## Attempted Solution 3 (FAILED)

I looked up a different way to disable click events using a blank `pointerInput` implementation. Since there is no `clickable` modifier the accessibility reader reads out the `content` composable and honours its semantics.

There is a deal breaker though. While this blocked touch events the accessibility reader is still able to select it.

```
@Composable
fun DisableOverlay(enabled: Boolean, alpha: Float = 0.45F, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    if (enabled) {
        content()
    } else {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .alpha(alpha)
        ) {
            content()

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .pointerInput(Unit){
                    //absorb the clicks
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

## Idea 1

If I set `contentDescription` on the `Box` that overlaps `content`, the reader reads it as expected. Ideally, I don't want to pass through a `contentDescription`, I want to just extract the semantics from `content` and just read it out. Is this possible?

```
@Composable
fun DisableOverlay(enabled: Boolean, alpha: Float = 0.45F, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    if (enabled) {
        content()
    } else {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .alpha(alpha)
        ) {
            content()

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .clickable(enabled = false){
                    //absorb the clicks
                }
                .semantics {
                    contentDescription = "test"
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

## Idea 2

My overall goal is to allow a `Composable` to be disabled just by wrapping it in another `Composable`. If anyone has an alternative solution to the above, please let me know.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Added `Attempted Solution 3` this failed but its getting close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea on the #3. You have to do it like this at the top level box though.

```kotlin
val intercepter by remember { mutableStateOf(RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent())}
Box(modifier = Modifier.pointerInteropFilter(intercepter) { motionEvent -> true }) {// box content}
```